# 2 Windows with the same name and class

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I have 2 windows with the same class and name.
Here is a picture of the 2 windows in SPY++

[image: the 2 windows]

I want to find the bottom window(`001C1E1A`) But whenever I'm trying to find him using this line:

```
hwndChild2 = FindWindowEx((IntPtr)hwndChild, IntPtr.Zero, "msctls_progress32", null);
```

I get the top window(`00790B50`) instead.

So my question is:
How can I find the bottom window(`001C1E1A`) from the list in the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa) the first argument of `FindWindowEx` is the **parent** window, and the **second** parameter is `childAfter`, the handle of the window you found before.

So these calls should give you the result:

```
// find first window
hwndChild = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "msctls_progress32", null);
// find second window
hwndChild2 = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)hwndChild, "msctls_progress32", null);
```